GraalVM polyglot not able to find installed language
I am getting this exception.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A language with id 'python' is not
installed. Installed languages are: [].
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineException.illegalArgument(PolyglotEngineException.java:131)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.throwNotInstalled(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1105)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotEngineImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotEngineImpl.java:1112)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.requirePublicLanguage(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1501)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.lookupLanguageContext(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1463)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextImpl.eval(PolyglotContextImpl.java:1472)
at org.graalvm.truffle/com.oracle.truffle.polyglot.PolyglotContextDispatch.eval(PolyglotContextDispatch.java:63)
at org.graalvm.sdk/org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:403)
at PythonInterop.main(PythonInterop.java:12)

import org.graalvm.polyglot.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class PythonInterop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Context context = Context.newBuilder().allowAllAccess(true).build()) {
            Source source = Source.newBuilder("python",
                    Paths.get("plot_graph.py").toFile()).build();
            context.eval(source);

            // Example: Retrieve the generated plot file and display its path
            File plotFile = new File("plot.png");
            if (plotFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Python plot generated at: " + plotFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Python plot file not found.");
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_graph():
    x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
    y = np.sin(x)

    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
    plt.plot(x, y, label='sin(x)')
    plt.title('Simple Plot using Matplotlib')
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('sin(x)')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('plot.png')  # Save the plot as a PNG file
    plt.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    plot_graph()

I am using GraalVM 17. No issue in compilation.
Python is installed on my system and I configured in environment variables.
I am using Python 3.12.4.
But still I am getting this issue. Can you please help me?

When you say "Python is installed on my system" what exactly do you mean?

This answer has python example in graalvm with maven, can you test with that ?
